# Practical demonstration of random number

Tags: random-number-generator, randomness

I am tasked with creating a practical demonstration of a random number.

This means, generating a random number, then showing something practical with it.

Does anyone happen to know something practical to do with it, or use it in a software, or a communication demonstration?

Comment: There are many interesting uses of a random numbers in software, including simulation, e.g. the [Galton board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galton_board), [random walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk), searching solutions of some classes of problem by [simulated annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing).

Comment: @fgrieu Especially in the field of communication (secure communication), can you think of a use case?

Comment: In the field of secure communication, use of random numbers include: generation of cryptographic keys (e.g. for AES-encrypted communication; session keys for e.g. [Diffie-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange)); generation of [nonces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce). If you [edit](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/101722/edit) the question (including title) on the tune of "usage of random numbers in secure communication", with mention in body that's for a demo, and giving some of your ideas with comment, maybe it will get re-opened.